# AngularJS unit test pascalprecht.translate not available

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'pascalprecht.translate' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/nomod?p0=pascalprecht.translate
  (anonymous function)
  (anonymous function)
  ensure
  module
  angular.module
  (anonymous function)
  (anonymous function)
  (anonymous function)

I have included in the index.html :
        '../js/angular-translate/*.js',

and in app.module :     angular.module('app name', [..,'pascalprecht.translate',])

Comment: Can you check whether the js file is loaded properly in chrome dev tool `Sources` tab?

Comment: I have the following directory structure :

>base
  >app name
    >other folders
    > somefiles
and here I'm missing the module file.

Could that be the issue ?